# Audio from .mkv file stutters when skipping in VLC

Tags: sound, vlc, mkv

Title basically says it all. When I'm using VLC and I jump to a random point in an .mkv video, the audio stutters a bit. It gets quite annoying after a while.

It doesn't happen in other video players, so is there a way to fix it in VLC without having to make changes to the .mkv file?

Edit: It's on a local drive.

Comment: I tried VLC and I also faced the stuttering you mention. As you have noticed, this doesn't happen with other players, so I think it's a VLC issue and not an issue with your `.mkv` file. Personally, I have had several similar issues with VLC and I don't use it any more, so I suggest that you use another video player. I highly recommend [mpv](https://mpv.io/) or [Celluloid](https://celluloid-player.github.io/), which is a graphical front-end for mpv.

Comment: Is the file on a local or remote drive? I have only ever seen this issue on a USB attached drive running the file from there. I have used VLC for many years and on various platforms and thousands of files and like I said only on an external file.